# How can i make the characters to stand in circle formation but facing inside?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now they are facing outside:

[image: Facing out]

The only thing i tried so far is to change the line:

```
var rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(pos - center);
```

To

```
var rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(pos + center);
```

But it didn't work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SquadFormation : MonoBehaviour
{
    enum Formation
    {
        Square, Circle
    }

    public Transform squadMemeber;
    public int columns = 4;
    public int space = 10;
    public int numObjects = 20;
    public float yOffset = 1;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        ChangeFormation();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void ChangeFormation()
    {
        Formation formation = Formation.Circle;

        switch (formation)
        {
            /*case Formation.Square:

                for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
                {
                    Transform go = Instantiate(squadMemeber);
                    Vector3 pos = FormationSquare(i);
                    go.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + pos.x, 0, transform.position.y + pos.y);
                    go.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -90, 0));
                }
                break;*/

            case Formation.Circle:

                Vector3 center = transform.position;
                for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++)
                {
                    Vector3 pos = RandomCircle(center, 5.0f);
                    var rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(pos - center);
                    pos.y = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(pos);
                    pos.y = pos.y + yOffset;
                    Instantiate(squadMemeber, pos, rot);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    Vector2 FormationSquare(int index) // call this func for all your objects
    {
        float posX = (index % columns) * space;
        float posY = (index / columns) * space;
        return new Vector2(posX, posY);
    }

    Vector3 RandomCircle(Vector3 center, float radius)
    {
        float ang = Random.value * 360;
        Vector3 pos;
        pos.x = center.x + radius * Mathf.Sin(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        pos.z = center.z + radius * Mathf.Cos(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        pos.y = center.y;
        return pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: why not have them transform.lookat(centralpoint.transform) and then simply rotate them 180 degrees?

Comment: @oxrock How to do it ? For now i only added the line squadMemeber.LookAt(center); before the var rot line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were so close. You have to switch the order of the variables in your  `LookRotation` function and also assign the variable to your object rotation after instantiating it.

Replace

```
var rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(pos - center);
```

with

```
var rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(center - pos);
```

then replace:

```
Instantiate(squadMemeber, pos, rot);
```

with

```
Transform insObj = Instantiate(squadMemeber, pos, rot);
insObj.rotation = rot;
```